# How to simulate an external event during testing at a particular point in code

Tags: testing, mocking

I am trying to work out the best way to simulate something bad happening at very specific points during the execution of code I’m testing, to make sure the code which is supposed to recover from the "bad thing" actually works as expected.

In my particular case I want to simulate a user making detrimental changes to various files, but really any arbitrary example you could think of would apply.

The simplest way I can think of to do this is to make calls to an empty “stub” method which would do nothing at all in production, but which I will mock out during testing with a patch to do the actual work of making the bad thing happen.  In my example the patch would rename or delete files which were being operated on by the script.

Consider the following generic example which is in Python but could be written in any language you'd like:

`script.py`:

```
def simulate_bad_thing_during_testing():
    # This is an intentionally empty stub to be mocked out during testing.
    pass

def main():
    # Do some work.
    ...

    simulate_bad_thing_during_testing()

    # Do some more work, even if bad thing has happened.
    ...
```

`test_script.py`:

```
def do_bad_thing():
    # Do the bad thing here.
    ...

@mock.patch('simulate_bad_thing_during_testing', side_effect=do_bad_thing)
def test_main_recovers_from_bad_thing():
    main()

    # assert all was well and the script recovered from the bad thing.
    ...
```

Is this way of doing it common practice?  I've been trying to find examples of this on the net and have failed.

If others have done it before, then what is it called?  Perhaps my Google-fu would be better if I had a better term for this.  I've come across "mutation" testing and "fuzz" testing, but both of those terms seem to denote something different.

Is there a better way to simulate arbitrary worst-case scenarios at particular points in code under test?  Perhaps one that won't raise the eyebrows of teammates wondering why I've chosen such an "invasive" way of doing this.  I do feel slightly uncomfortable with such tight coupling between the implementation of my function and the tests covering the function, but how else can I "hook" into a particular line in this fashion?

Comment: Why you would like add a specific hook point? Every time you would test some bad things this bad thing can happen from some code with some responsibilities: extract this code and use side effect on it.

Comment: Not *every* time.  What I want to simulate is an *external* event -- for example a user making changes to files independently of the software.  The files are necessary for the software to run, sure, but the "external" event that could change them are completely separate.

Comment: Sure, but your software should have a point where *recognize* file changing and read new file: that is the hook point. That means you should patch the read function and inject a new *file changed* event. IMHO is better don't mixing test and production code and experience told me that there are already valid hooks almost every time (just decorators and functions defined in functions can eventually break this rule).

Comment: Ah, I see where you are coming from now.  Thanks for making it clear.  And yes, mixing test and production code was indeed my main concern.

If you're into the whole Stackoverflow rep score thing, I'll accept what you've said as an answer if you type it up.